# How to select Dynamic X-Path Value

Tags: user-interface, xpath, pyautogui

Xpath for the Icon is //*[@id="csfWidgets-button-9746-content"]
the number is changing for every time when I open the browser

Also I tried below Xpath value

//*[@id="csfWidgets-button-9746-content"]

//*[@id="csfWidgets-button-entry-content"]

//div[starts-with(@id,"csfWidgets-button-")]

//div[contains(@id,"csfWidgets")]

But still I am facing below issue

```
ValueError: Element locator '//div[starts-with(@id,"csfWidgets-button-")]' did not match any elements.
```

Please help to resolve this issue , suggestion given will be appreciated

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I suppose the XPath is version 1.0 and that has no starts-with function.
The last XPath (//div[contains(@id,"csfWidgets")]), should give you result.
If not, something else is wrong.

Comment: I tried with this Xpath (//div[contains(@id,"csfWidgets")]), but still the same issue 
ValueError: Element locator '(//div[contains(@id,"csfWidgets")])' did not match any elements.

Comment: I have added the photo of Xpath, please look into it once & give me a suggestion to resolve this issue

Comment: Still XPath should work. Something else is wrong. Maybe dom not completely loaded? I have no knowledge of pyautogui